# How can I use application/ld for rent car site?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I want to increase the attractiveness of the site in a search engine and I want to use a microdata.

But I did not find a single example of application/ld micromarking for a car rental website. I could find only microdata for email notifications.

Is there a micro markup for rental car sites?

Answer (score 1):

Have you really looked for it on schema.org?

https://schema.org/AutoRental

There is even a generator for a simple schema:

https://schema.pythonanywhere.com/AutoRental

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutoRental">
<span itemprop="description">description</span>
<span itemprop="image">image</span>
<span itemprop="name">rent a vw</span>
<span itemprop="potentialAction">rent</span>
<span itemprop="url">/rent/</span>
</div>
```